# Struggles unpacking a two-dimensional list in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm passing a bunch of data into my template but am having a hard time breaking apart a zipped list of items.  No matter what I try, I always get the following error.

> Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 0.

Heres my code:

**views.py**

```
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

dictionary, words = [[], []], []


def home(request, username='johnny'):
    template_name = 'main/index.html'
    url = "https://www.duolingo.com/users/{}".format(username)
    getUserData(url)
    context = {
        'username': username,
        'dictionary': dictionary,
        'words': words,
    }
    # print(context)
    return render(request, template_name, context)


def getUserData(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    userdata = response.json()
    wordlists, explanations = [], []

    for language in userdata['language_data']:
        for index in userdata['language_data'][language]['skills']:
            if index.get('levels_finished') > 0:
                wordList = index.get("words")
                wordlists.append(wordList)
                explanations.append(index.get("explanation"))
                for wordItem in wordList:
                    words.append(wordItem)
    dictionary = list(zip(wordlists, explanations))
```

**relevant template**

```
{% block content %}
    {% for words, exp in dictionary %}
      {{ words }}
      {{ exp|safe }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I've tested this code, it works.

[image]

Once I refactored in Django to put wordLists in an array with explanations, things go to hell.  If I `print(dictionary)` at the end of the method, the data shows in the console.  Not sure what else I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with [scope](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php). the dictionary(variable) which you are returning from `home` function(as context) and dictionary in `getUserData` function are not in same scope. So whenever you are updating `getUserData` method's dictionary, its not being updated in `home`. I would not recommend your approach for dictionary as [its using global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil). I would recommend something like this:

```
def getUserData(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    userdata = response.json()
    wordlists, explanations, words = [], [], []

    for language in userdata['language_data']:
        for index in userdata['language_data'][language]['skills']:
            if index.get('levels_finished') > 0:
                wordList = index.get("words")
                wordlists.append(wordList)
                explanations.append(index.get("explanation"))
                for wordItem in wordList:
                    words.append(wordItem)
    return list(zip(wordlists, explanations)), words  # return the value of dictionary from here


def home(request, username='johnny'):
    template_name = 'main/index.html'
    url = "https://www.duolingo.com/users/{}".format(username)
    dictionary, words = getUserData(url)  # catch value of dictionary
    context = {
        'username': username,
        'dictionary': dictionary,
        'words': words,
    }
    # print(context)
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Comment: I realize my code is neither pythonic or best practice. I threw it together to see if a rough product creates inspiration. Thanks.  I'll work on it some more using your suggestions.

Comment: Made a small change but it seems to work.  Got a pesky json decoder error now though.  lol